# How to make a cloudant query to find documents which two fields are equal

Tags: nosql, couchdb, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I need to get all documents whose e.g. "_id" field equal to another document field, e.g. "appId"

```
{
  "_id": "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx",
  "_rev": "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx",
  "header": {
    "appId": "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
```

So what would be the query?

```
   "selector": {
      "_id": {
         "$eq": header.appId
      }
   },
```

Comment: What query(s) did you try?

Comment: I tried the query that is in my question

Answer (score 0):

You can't do "sub queries" with Mango.

From what I see, you're trying to get all the documents listed by appId.

This could be done by using a view.

Your map function would be the following:

```
if(doc.header && doc.header.appId){
    emit(doc.doc.header.appId,{_id: doc.header.appId});
}
```

The result would be a list of documents mapped by `doc.header.appId`.

If you query the view with `?include_docs=true`, the documents would be joined to the response since we're doing a ManyToJoin join.